# Maxout at town hall 8, or move on to level 9?

Tags: clash-of-clans

[image: my th8 base]

I have heard from high players in global that upgrading buildings later on in the game is hard as available loot from town halls 7 and 8 in multiplayer battle reduces drastically.

I have uploaded a picture of my base and  I want to ask should I upgrade my town hall to level 9 or stay at level 8.

Things I have taken into consideration:

- available loot in multiplayer will reduce
- research lab takes about 10 days to upgrade a single unit, so elixir storages fill up (accumulated due to multiplayer attacks) and elixir is not used much as every thing requires town hall 9.
- mostly dark elixir loot available in town hall 8's is good comparatively to level 7's ; upgrading the town hall won't be a problem for dark elixir.
- high town hall level will keep my accumulated elixir constantly in use for upgrading troops.
- if you see carefully my all builders are free so time is wasted. (I could have upgraded many things if I were town hall 9)
- I still have too many walls at level 7 upgrading them later will be hard.

So after considering all the things from above, should I upgrade my town hall to level 9?

Here see my profile

[image: my profile]

I hope this post helps to other players who are in same doubt.

Comment: As a general rule, you want to essentially max everything out before you advance. My personal exception to this is not maxing walls because its so expensive. Really, theres no yes/no answer to this question because its completely an opinion

Comment: I am asking for experience of high level players I really mean lvl110+ or something

Comment: Well what is more profitable  ?    Upgrading th  or  staying in current state and upgrading walls?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your profile? It would help to see what troops you have

Comment: Yes I will edit my question and add picture

Comment: i'd say yes because if you look at the [wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Town_Hall) not only to you get another Wizard Tower and Archer Tower plus traps and the last 25 units of wall but also you can start building your X-Bows, you get your final gold/elixir storage and you can get your archer queen. otherwise what else are you going to use all those resources for? as you get more trophies you'll face up against those who have better defenses so you need the troop upgrades and your own defences upgraded for when they attack

Comment: On the other hand though, that adds an extra cost - upgrading the extra buildings, plus managing the extra costs of further upgrades that may become available. If you level up now, your castle will be better equipped to defend. However if you upgrade now, yes you may have extra resources at your disposal, however you will also have to manage those *as well as* managing anything else that hasn't been fully upgraded, like walls.

Comment: Yes upgrading walls is a mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my personal opinion, if you want to go to TH9 then that is completely up to you. Rushing a bit to TH9 will not hurt you, especially with your current troop and building levels.

The one thing you should be careful to avoid is rushing to TH10, as that will cause your building advancement to decrease dramatically.

Personally I thought maxing was the best plan back when I was TH8. I maxed everything except about half of my walls before upgrading. While it was nice, it was not necessary. Currently I am a level 109 TH9, working on maxing out :)

Comment: * The one thing you should be careful to avoid is rushing to TH10, as that will cause your building advancement to decrease dramatically. *  seriously ?

Comment: Yes, seriously, the loot goes bat sh** up there XD So what you'll want to do is stay at TH9 until it is completely maxed out. My plan is to max out walls and heroes at TH9, no matter how long that will take. Because of elixir for walls at level 9+, I'm not worried about wasting elixir (which is why I slightly rushed TH9).

Answer (score 4):

You really should max out everything first or your going to spend lvl 9 wishing you had. This is a perfect level to focus in war so if you find it boring to build up everything, just focus on going trophys instead...

Comment: Yay you gave me a direction what should I do.  So I will continue to upgrade walls and concentrate in wars. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say completely max out if you haven't already gone to th9. The reason being is your attacks are going to change. You can debate walls...I'd say max them, but that's just me... But as far as everything else...you need your golems maxed, your pekkas maxed, you want your barb king to 10 because of the boost from that. Then you fill storages and ug so you can hit the ground running with archer queen, Xbows, lab ug, and getting your new ad and other stuff up. Spend the time in th8 and you'll get through 9 faster. War attack strategy relies heavily on drags for most in th8, but in 9 you need gowipe, gowiwi. Also if you practice them now (with maxed gols and pekks) you'll be a more effective teammate.

Comment: Yes. I was wondering why no one mentioned anything about Pekka. You can upgrade them to level 3 in town hall 8. With all the surplus elixir, its easier to do it in TH 8. If you dont upgrade them then you will spend atleast a month in TH 9 just to bring it up to level 3. I made the same mistake with hogs. I spent over a month to upgrade them from level 1.

Answer (score 3):

I was in the exact same position as you. But I ended up upgrading.

I always get attacked by level 110s now and I am only a level 80. I hardly ever have any gold, but elixir I always have plenty of. But still not enough for me to proceed in the game. I started playing October 2012 and quit in early 2014 because of my mistakes. There was no way I'd ever start over, but I didn't want to continue where I was at.

So no, do not upgrade yet. Definitely max out.

Comment: I upgraded my th to level 9 after I got Jacob's answer.

Comment: Which is completely fine, @Fennekin , with the setup you have it is already better than mine, and I upgraded at least a year ago now :)

Comment: at that point you should have dropped

Comment: @bleh what are you trying to say? In my answer I obviously stated that I quit over 2 years ago.

Comment: I know, but you should have dropped at the time

Answer (score 2):

Be wary if you upgrade your TH now it will be harder to find loot.  There is a thing called a "Loot Penalty".  Here is a graph to help you along.  For Example lets say you have a Lv.5 TH attacking a Lv.5 TH with Maxed out storages, Clash only lets you take 20% of their 1,000,000 so you'd have 200,000  available

[image: Gold/Elixir Storages—Percent Lootable by Town Hall Level]

[image: Town Hall Levels—Loot Multiplier]

> [Source](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids)

But this decision is up to you, It's your game I am just here to give advice.

Clash on!